# Pointers with arrays: char* getCharacterAddress(char array[][arraySize], int row, int column):

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, implementation

I'm just doing trying to fill the empty implementation in function.h but I don't understand how to.

In the main.cpp test I have the following:

```
TEST_CASE("Testing getCharacterAddress()"){
const unsigned int rows = 5;
const unsigned int columns = 5;

char first[rows][columns] = {
    {'f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't'},
    {'s', 'e', 'c', 'o', 'n'},
    {'t', 'h', 'i', 'r', 'd'},
    {'f', 'o', 'u', 'r', 't'},
    {'f', 'i', 'f', 't', 'h'}
};

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        void* address = getCharacterAddress(first, i, j);
        INFO("Testing Address: " << address << " to contain: " << first[i][j]);
        REQUIRE(*(char*)address == first[i][j]);
    }
}
```

}

Now in the function.h I have the following function:

char* getCharacterAddress(char(*array)[arraySize], int row, int column)

I understand that the function takes a 2D array, a row and a column but I don't know how to obtain the address value for a specific row and col combination.

Please help me and thank you!! :)

Comment: `address == &first[i][j]` I would imagine.

Answer (score 0):

To get an adress of a variable in c++ use an ampersand, `&`. For example, consider

```
int a = 1;
int* b = &a;
```

`b` is a pointer becasue it points to `a` (and its value is the adress of `a`).

Similarly, the implementation of your function would look like

```
char* getCharacterAddress(char arr[rows][columns], int row, int col){
    return &arr[row][col];  // return the adress of the specified char
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the address of an entry of a 2D-array, right?

There is the address operator `&` to retrieve the address of an object:

```
char* getCharacterAddress(char array[][5], size_t i, size_t j) { 
    return & array[i][j];
}
```